# Why does an empty UIScrollView have two subviews?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a need to calculate the height of of my content within a UIScrollView.

I dropped an empty UIScrollView into the XCode Storyboard, gave it a custom class with this code:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++) {
            UIView *view =[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"sub view %@ x:%f, y:%f, w:%f, h:%f", [view class], view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

With an empty UIScrollView this is what logs to the console:

```
sub view UIImageView x:233.000000, y:121.000000, w:7.000000, h:7.000000
sub view UIImageView x:233.000000, y:121.000000, w:7.000000, h:7.000000
```

What are those images? They throw off my calculations because they are always below my content.

Comment: My guess is the scroll bars but I have nothing to back that statement... Also, `NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame);` will save you some typing next time printing a frame

Comment: I had figured it'd be the scroll bars too, but don't know how to prove that. Thanks for NSStringFromCGRect :)

Comment: Well, if you remove all subviews with `for(UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}`, you'd notice that the scrollbars disappear.

Comment: You should keep track of the content you're adding to the scrollview and iterate through that to do your calculations, not through the subviews of the scrollview. You never know what kind of weird stuff Apple could be doing under the hood (such as adding scrollbars).

Comment: Anshu, if I was adding content in code I completely agree, however I'm working with scrollview that has content added via the XCode storyboard, so it has existing content. Short of tagging/labeling each item in the Storyboard, I don't know how to differentiate between the items I've added, and those Apple added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're the scrollbars (or scroll indicators, if you prefer.) One is horizontal and the other is vertical.